# How to design an clogn time algorithm of 2 sorted array to find median of all 2N?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search, median-of-medians

I have given a question that there is given two array A and B are sorted in ascending order. I need to design an clogn time algorithm to find the median of all 2N integers. The question noted that the N may not power of 2. Hint to solve the question is find min and max of both array then change the input and make length to power of 2.

My current problem:
Since two array are sorted so the first element will be min and last element will be max for both arrays. Then here how can i change the input and make the length to power of 2?

Comment: Why do you want to change the input?

Comment: Because I want to make the length to power of 2

Comment: @DAle u doesn't ans what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design of an algorithm problems of Clog n\[C++ code\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691363/design-of-an-algorithm-problems-of-clog-nc-code)

Comment: You don't need to make the length a power of 2.

Comment: what means?????